# Array update from thread

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

I have trouble understanding the code below. My main problem is why the "a" array is updated with the values that are assigned to the "table" array in a thread.To be more specific i would like to have an explanation on why the "a" array doesn't print the initial elements (0,1,2,3...) .

The code of the main method and the thread :

```
public class ThreadParSqrt
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double[] a = new double[1000];

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            a[i] = i;

        SqrtThread threads[] = new SqrtThread[1000];

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            threads[i] = new SqrtThread(a,i);
            threads[i].start();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            try {
                threads[i].join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class SqrtThread extends Thread
{
    private double [] table;
    private int index;

    public SqrtThread(double [] array, int ind)
    {
        table = array;
        index = ind;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        table[index] = Math.sqrt(table[index]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `a` is passed to the constructor of `SqrtThread` by reference (search pass by reference/pass by value). In that constructor the reference, now called `array` is then stored in the private member `table`. But since it's a reference, any change to `table` will also be a change in `a` (because both references point to the same array in memory).

I should also probably warn you about thread-safety and so, but it seems like you're still learning the basics. Once you grab those, you might want to read up on thread synchronisation, locks, events, etc.